# SQL error [21000]: ERROR: a subquery used as an expression returned more than one record

Tags: sql

The Remesa table has a relationship N to 1 with EnvioRemesa, the issue is that I want to update my delete bit to 1 of the Remesa table, but only update the Remesa that have a EnvioRemesa id = 2. And it is failing me in the query since in the subquery it returns 2 matching records and tries to compare them with r.id. Any way to fix this?

```
update remesa r 
set borrado=1 
where r.envio_remesa_id= (
                          select r.id from remesa r 
                          inner join envio_remesa er 
                            on r.envio_remesa_id=er.id 
                          where er.id=2
                         )
```

Comment: Please share more details, like the table structure and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: If you want to update more than 1 record change your = to IN (..) for your where clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't need a subquery. I bet you can simply inner join directly to the envio_remesa table.

```
update r  
set r.borrado=1 
FROM remesa as r
inner join dbo.envio_remesa er on r.envio_remesa_id=er.id 
where er.id=2
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someones need , i have a solution , using the IN operator like @Brad said it.For update multiple records

```
update remesa r 
set borrado=1 
where r.id
in (
    select r.id 
    from remesa r
    inner join envio_remesa er 
    on r.envio_remesa_id=er.id 
    where er.id=2)
```